# laravel with intervention package maximum image upload validation

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

So i'm using intervention package to save and also resize my image if it has to big resolution, but i get MethodNotAllowedHttpException when i tried to test with uploading big images (around 10 mb ).

so i do some research over here and the net, there is indeed some answer but none of them work with me, i wonder why is it happen?

```
try{
    $img = Input::file('gambar');

    if(!empty($img)){

        $file_max = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
        $file_max_str_leng = strlen($file_max);
        $file_max_meassure_unit = substr($file_max,$file_max_str_leng - 1,1);
        $file_max_meassure_unit = $file_max_meassure_unit == 'K' ? 'kb' : ($file_max_meassure_unit == 'M' ? 'mb' : ($file_max_meassure_unit == 'G' ? 'gb' : 'unidades'));
        $file_max = substr($file_max,0,$file_max_str_leng - 1);
        $file_max = intval($file_max);

        $filename = $img->getClientOriginalName();


        $size = $img->getSize();

        if ($size < $file_max){
            if($this->save_image($img,$artikel,$filename)){
                $artikel->update(array(
                    'judul' => $judul,
                    'content' => Input::get('content'),
                    'kategori' => Input::get('kategori'),
                    'status' => Input::get('status'),
                    'pilihan' => Input::get('pilihan'),
                    'gambar' => $filename
                    ));
            }else{
                return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
            }
        }else{
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('errormessage','El tamaño del archivo debe ser menor que %smb.',$file_max);
        }           
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('errormessage','The file size should be lower than %s%s.',$file_max,$file_max_meassure_unit);
}
```

and here is my save_image function

```
function save_image($img,$artikel,$filename){

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img);

    $path = public_path('images_artikel/');
    File::delete($path . $artikel->gambar);

    if($width > 1280 && $height > 720){
        if(Image::make($img->getRealPath())->resize('1280','720')->save($path . $filename))
            return true;
        else
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('errormessage','Terjadi kesalahan dalam penyimpanan');
    }else{
        if(Image::make($img->getRealPath())->save($path . $filename))
            return true;
        else
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('errormessage','Terjadi kesalahan dalam penyimpanan');
    }
}
```

i also tried to use validation rules in my models but not working...

```
private $file_max;

function _construct(){
    $file_max = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    $file_max_str_leng = strlen($file_max);
    $file_max_meassure_unit = substr($file_max,$file_max_str_leng - 1,1);
    $file_max_meassure_unit = $file_max_meassure_unit == 'K' ? 'kb' : ($file_max_meassure_unit == 'M' ? 'mb' : ($file_max_meassure_unit == 'G' ? 'gb' : 'unidades'));
    $file_max = substr($file_max,0,$file_max_str_leng - 1);
    $file_max = intval($file_max);
}

// Add your validation rules here
public static $rules = [
     'judul' => 'required|between:5,255',
     'content' => 'required',
     'gambar' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,bmp|max:{$file_max}'

];
```

here is my route

```
Route::resource('artikels','AdminArtikelsController');
```

and my form

```
{{ Form::model($artikel, array('route' => array('admin.artikels.update',$artikel->id), 'method' => 'put', 'files' => true)) }}
```

so is there other solution?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best practice is to create your custom validator like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Validators;


use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomImageValidator extends Validator {

    public function validateMaxResolution($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $this->requireParameterCount(1, $parameters, 'max_resolution');

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($value);
        $resolution = explode('x', $parameters[0]);
        $max_width = $resolution[0];
        $max_height = $resolution[1];

        return ($width <= $max_width && $height <= $max_height);
    }

    protected function replaceMaxResolution($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
    {
        return str_replace(':value', implode(', ', $parameters), $message);
    }

}
```

Then register the validator in `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Validators\CustomImageValidator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        { // custom image validator ;)
            return new CustomImageValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

In your `resource/lang/en/validation.php` add your default message:

```
 'max_resolution'           => 'The :attribute image resolution is too large to resize. Max resolution is :value.',
```

And finally add your rule to the rules array:

```
'your_image_field' => 'required|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,bmp|max:1024|max_resolution:3000x3000'
```

This was tested on *Laravel 5.1.16 (LTS)*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the route you use it as action attribute in the form is of type post, and also that the form has files activated.
Something like this:

For the route:

```
Route::post('upload', array('uses' => 'UploadController@handleUpload', 'as' => 'upload'));
```

For the form:

```
Form::open(array('route' => 'upload', 'files' => true));
```

Comment: Can you post also the output of ```artisan routes```?

Answer (score 0):

check two things:

1. In your phpinfo.php: `memory_limit` and `upload_max_filesize`
2. If your image processor is GD, try: `Image::configure(array('driver' => 'imagick'));`

hope that helps